# Setting the Textbox read only property to true using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, textbox, readonly

How do you set the Textbox read only property to true or false using JavaScript in ASP.NET?

Comment: You could use setAttribute but it has some major browser issues (outlined here: http://reference.sitepoint.com/javascript/Element/setAttribute). Just putting it out there as an option.

Answer (score 35):

You can try

```
document.getElementById("textboxid").readOnly = true;
```

Comment: this doesn't always work. see the answer by SteveCinq below

Answer (score 6):

I find that `document.getElementById('textbox-id').readOnly=true` sometimes doesn't work reliably.

Instead, try:

`document.getElementById('textbox-id').setAttribute('readonly', 'readonly')` and
`document.getElementById('textbox-id').removeAttribute('readonly')`.

A little verbose but it seems to be dependable.

Comment: this is the only way that actually worked for me

Answer (score 3):

`document.getElementById('textbox-id').readOnly=true` should work

Comment: Try lowercasing the "O" in readonly. Alternatively you could try using the "disabled" attribute with true and false values. The two attributes are only subtly different (http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/interact/forms.html#adef-disabled).

Answer (score 2):

Try This :-

set Read Only False ( Editable TextBox)

```
document.getElementById("txtID").readOnly=false;
```

set Read Only true(Not Editable )

```
var v1=document.getElementById("txtID");
v1.setAttribute("readOnly","true");
```

This can work on IE and Firefox also.

Answer (score 0):

Using asp.net, I believe you can do it this way :

```
myTextBox.Attributes.Add("readonly","readonly")
```

Answer (score 0):

it depends on how you trigger the event. the key you are looking is textbox.clientid.

x.aspx code

```
<script type="text/javascript">

   function disable_textbox(tid) {
        var mytextbox = document.getElementById(tid);
         mytextbox.disabled=false
   }
</script>
```

code behind x.aspx.cs

```
    string frameScript = "<script language='javascript'>" + "disable_textbox(" + tx.ClientID  ");</script>";
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "FrameScript", frameScript);
```

Comment: `disabled` is not the same as `readOnly`. `disabled` will not send the form data for the element whereas `readOnly` will.