# Setting input field readonly with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm setting the value for SecretAttribute dynamically via another script, but at the moment I'm having difficulties making the Name input field as `readonly`.

Tried setting the `getElementByID` by SecretAttribute and SecretElement, but no dice..

```
<input name="SecretAttribute" id="SecretAttribute" value="Y" type="checkbox" checked/> 
<html>
<head>
 <title>Demo Title</title>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
var SecretElement = document.getElementById('SecretAttribute');\
if (document.getElementById("SecretAttribute").checked;) {
    function DataCheck() {
    document.getElementById('Name').readOnly = true;
  } 
}

</script>
</head>
<body onload="DataCheck()">

  Demo6.1<br>
  Name: <input type="text" id="Name" name="Name"><br>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What does *but no dice* mean? What exactly isn't working? that is the correct way to set the readonly attribute. Have you debugged this code?

Comment: Why is the input element before the html element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Function call was inside the if statement. Put the if condition inside the call

```js
  function DataCheck() {
    if(document.getElementById("SecretAttribute").checked)
    document.getElementById('Name').readOnly = true;
  } 

var SecretElement = document.getElementById('SecretAttribute');
```

```html
<input name="SecretAttribute" id="SecretAttribute" value="Y" type="checkbox" checked/> 
<html>
<head>
 <title>Demo Title</title>

</head>
<body onload="DataCheck()">

  Demo6.1<br>
  Name: <input type="text" id="Name" name="Name" value="You can't edit this"><br>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your using older browsers try using [setAttribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute), something like...

```
  var SecretElement = document.getElementById('SecretAttribute');
  if (SecretElement.checked) {
    document.getElementById('Name').setAttribute("readonly","readonly");
  }
```

Comment: [There is nothing wrong with that way of setting readonly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1759343/542251)

Comment: If you read the comments on the thread you've linked to, this doesn't work in all browsers

Comment: This was likely true in 2009

Comment: IE10, whilst a dog, still exists. The asker hasn't said what browser they are using.

Comment: Without explicit information on what browser he needs supporting `setAttribute` is dangerous.

Comment: How is it dangerous?